# python + selenuim как достать текст с элемента

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

На сайте есть такой элемент нужно вывести текст помогите пожалуйста

```
<div class="korp_skolko_do_chsla_1">
          <div class="korp_skolko_do_dni">
               <span class="korp_skolko_do_chsla_cifr_1" id="den_dan">345</span> <span
```

Comment: ссылка на сайт: https://calculator888.ru/skolko-dney-do-novogo-goda/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз у элемента есть `id`, то по нему и лучше всего вытаскивать значение:

```
den_dan_el = driver.find_element_by_id('den_dan')
print(den_dan_el.text)
```